# Jupyter cells have no ouput

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel, jupyter-console

new to python. My code is using JSON to look at js dictionary online.  I can execute simple print statements from inside of the dictionary I have made, but if I try to print from within a for-loop or a function the cell has no output. It also doesn't throw an error though. I have tried it in different browser and have recently uninstalled and installed Anaconda in order to resolve another issue (which could be related, I was having trouble importing a package from Anaconda and had to initialize the package in jupyter.)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please read the following documentation, then [edit] and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as text** & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
from IPython.display import JSON
JSON(json_object, expanded=True)
```